# How do I animate a slingshot?

Tags: animation

[image: Slingshot model]

Hi I am trying to animate the slingshot to launch but i don't know how. Some help on how to animate a slingshot is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Hello, the simplest way to do it would be to use shapekeys, have you tried? Or you could parent it to an armature

Comment: It doesn't have any of this stuff can you show me how to do shape keys or armature

Comment: I am still having trouble can i send you the slingshot model and see if you can apply your curve answer on it

Comment: sure, use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions and copy paste the link in this page)

Comment: ok I posted it.

Comment: Hello, what are supposed to be the different shapes of the elastic? Maybe show a storyboard?

Comment: Ok i sent a updated blender file with the parts of the slingshot sepearated the part that says SlingshotRubber is the one that is the elastic part

Comment: hello, you should tell a bit more about your project, what is the animation for, is a character supposed to handle the object, what are the key shapes of the animation (before, after), etc

Comment: the slingshot is for a character i am making in a game and i wanted the character to shoot a waterballoon that i will make later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a lot of ways to do it, you can do it with 3 shapekeys, first the basic shapekey:

[image]

Second shapekey (tension):

[image]

Third shapekey (projection):

[image]

Result once you keyframe the shapekeys:

[image]

Another solution, with *Curve* modifier, create a curve that has the basic shape of your elastic, create a mesh that will be a segment of your elastic, array it with an *Array* modifier, *Fit Type > Fit Curve* with the curve as *Curve*. Also give the object a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]

Now select your curve, switch to *Edit* mode, select its middle control point, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > Hook to *New Object*. It will hook the point to an empty:

[image]

Now you can animate the empty:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For something like [this](https://youtu.be/rOW0Dbur9nE?si=sDIZzxr-iaqhLd_f) I would try mesh line from a few like low poly line ...

[image]

with hooked end points and middle point ... animate **Hooks** position and use **Cloth** modifier after that (to get it work you have to set Vertex Group of hooked points to be set under Cloth Properties > Shape > as Pin group.

[image]

[image]

- Subdivision Modifier ...

[image]

### Edit

for the rubber strip I wanted to use *Surface Deform* modifier, but it requires faces ... so instead of mesh line start with a mesh strip (Hooks and Cloth as before) ...

[image]

- Subdivision and Solidify modifier ...

[image]

[image]